# Cant show Images in react native flat list android

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I wanna build a flat list that contains images and text. The text is showing well but the images are not, even the local images. When I first used a ScrollView all elements displayed perfectly. I am using Windows 10 and the Android emulator. Here is my code:

```
> import React, {Component} from 'react';
> import {FlatList, Image, StyleSheet,Text, View} from "react-native";
> 
> export default class Articles extends Component {
>     constructor(props) {
>         super(props);
>         this.state = {
>             FlatListItems: [
>                 {
>                     TheKey: 'موسیقی',
>                     MATN: 'این ها هر کدام یک هنر هستند',
>                     IMAGE: {uri: 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png'}
>                 },
>                 {
>                     TheKey: 'نقاشی',
>                     MATN: 'این ها هر کدام یک هنر هستند',
>                     IMAGE: {uri: 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png'}
>                 },
>                 {
>                     TheKey: 'شعر',
>                     MATN: 'این ها هر کدام یک هنر هستند',
>                     IMAGE: {uri: 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png'}
>                 },
>                 {
>                     TheKey: 'رقص',
>                     MATN: 'این ها هر کدام یک هنر هستند',
>                     IMAGE: {uri: 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png'}
>                 }
>             ]
>         }
>     }
> 
>     _renderItem(item) {
>         return (
>             <ItemShow i={item.item}/>
>         )
> 
>     }
> 
>     render() {
>         return (
>             <View>
>                 {/*<Image source={{uri:'http://www.balout.ir/sitefiles/offices_logo.png'}}
> style={styles.image}/>*/}
> 
>                 <FlatList
>                     data={this.state.FlatListItems}
>                     renderItem={({item}) => this._renderItem({item})}
>                     keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
>                 />
>             </View>
> 
> 
>         )
> 
> 
>     } }
> 
> 
> class ItemShow extends Component {
>     constructor(props) {
>         super(props);
> 
> 
>     }
> 
>     render() {
> 
>         return (
>             <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
> 
>                 <Image source={{uri: this.props.IMAGE}} style={styles.image}></Image>
>                 <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column'}}>
>                     <Text style={styles.basListText}> {this.props.i.TheKey} </Text>
>                     <Text style={styles.listMatn}> {this.props.i.MATN} </Text>
>                 </View>
> 
>             </View>
>         )
> 
>     }
> 
> }
```

When I am having images in the screen, the images are not getting rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You have already pass the uri in source path, in array you add the image as                    `IMAGE: {uri: 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png'}`
but you should pass as only

```
IMAGE: 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png'
```

that would help you, please try it..

Comment: the base of images are showing but there place are white

Comment: have u declare the height and width of that view?

Comment: and add a just a background color so that identify that image view is created

Comment: use this line >                 <Image source={{uri: 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png'}} style={styles.image}></Image>
and let me know that it give the result or not

Comment: i have gave it that code but it still showing the background color

Comment: please add resizeMode:"contain" in style

Comment: image: {
        width: '50%',
        height: 100,
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        resizeMode:"contain"

    }

Comment: the backgtoundcolor still showing but i cant see the image

Comment: please change the height and width of the image in style

Comment: after changes just the backgroundColor Changes

Comment: i think image size is too long ,it takes time to load , please take the another image url and try it...

Comment: i have changed the image and resized it but nothing

Comment: does it see any other view like text(TheKey etc.)

Comment: yes i can seethe others and change there style except the image

Answer (score 0):

There's a little mistake in your ItemShow component!
you have :

```
<Image source={{uri: this.props.IMAGE}} ...
```

please change it to :

```
<Image source={{uri: this.props.i.IMAGE.uri}} ...
```